# How many red nodes does a red-black-tree with black height bh(t) have(at most)?

Tags: height, red-black-tree

How many red nodes does a red-black-tree with black height bh(t) have(at most)?

bh(t) = It is the number of black nodes on any simple path

A red black tree in our lecture is a binary search tree with

1. All node have 2 children(except leaf nodes)
2. Evry node is red or black
3. The root and all leaf nodes are black
4. All children of a red node are black
5. A Black node can at most have one red children
6. All paths from the root to the leaf have the same number of black nodes

I cant find the answer. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do note that this definition is a bit more constrained than the usual one: in the standard definition requirement 5 is not present, and red nodes can be siblings. But given this extra restriction we can make the following analysis:

- The only tree that has a black-height of 0 is the empty tree.
- The only tree that has a black-height of 1 is a single black node (root & leaf)

The first tree that comes to mind that has a black-height of 2 is the following one:

```
                 b
                / \
               b   b
```

We can choose one of those two leaves to expand into a red node with two black children:

```
                 b
                / \
               R   b
              / \
             b   b
```

We cannot do more. There is no way to inject a second red node. The mirror of this tree is the only other possibility to stay within the constraints you have listed, and have a black-height of 2.

This shape is a key in incrementing to the next black-height of 3 (and greater). I will call this tree *T*.

To produce a tree with a black-height of 3, with as many red nodes as possible, we can *replace* each leaf (there are 3) with a copy of *T*. The result is this:

```
                 _____ b_____
                /            \
               R              b
             /   \           / \
           b       b        R   b
          / \     / \      / \
         R   b   R   b    b   b
        / \     / \
       b   b   b   b
```

Again, we can mirror the different subtrees, but there is no way to get more red nodes in a tree with a black-height of 3.

Now consider this: in this expansion we replaced each existing leaf with *T*, and since *T* has one red node, we actually added the same number of red nodes as there were leaves. And since *T* has 3 leaves, we multiplied the number of leaves by 3, which will determine how many *T* trees we will inject at the next expansion... etc.

This gives us a recurrence relation -- I write *r<sub>h</sub>* to represent the maximum number of red nodes in a tree of black height *h*:

- r<sub>0</sub> = 0
- r<sub>1</sub> = 0
- r<sub>2</sub> = 1
- r<sub>h</sub> = 1 + 3r<sub>h-1</sub>

In a direct formula that last equation becomes:

- r<sub>h</sub> = ∑<sub><sub>i=1..h-2</sub></sub> 3<sup>i</sup>

Such sums can be rewritten as a repetition of 1 digits in base 3 notation, and so we can derive:

- r<sub>h</sub> = (3<sup>h-1</sup> - 1) / 2

This formula gives the correct result also for *h=1* and *h=2*, so we only need to add the case for *h=0*:

- r<sub>0</sub> = 0
- r<sub>h</sub> = (3<sup>h-1</sup> - 1) / 2, when *h > 0*

Here is a table with the first few results:

```
black height (h) | max number of red nodes (r[h])
-----------------+----------------------------------------
           0     |     0
           1     |     0
           2     |     1
           3     |     4
           4     |    13
           5     |    40
           6     |   121
           7     |   364
           8     |  1093
          ...    |   ...
           h     |  (3^(h-1) - 1) / 2
```